# Typemap javaimports doesn't work for inner C++ class

Tags: java, c++, swig, inner-classes, nested-class

Assuming I have `nested.i` like :

```
%typemap(javaimports) Outer "
/**
* Outer class
*/"

%typemap(javaimports) Outer::Inner "
/**
* Outer::Inner class
*/"

%javamethodmodifiers Outer::outer_method(int) "
  /**
  * Outer::outer_method(int)
  */
  public";

%javamethodmodifiers Outer::Inner::inner_method(int) "
  /**
  * Outer::Inner::inner_method(int)
  */
  public";

struct Outer {
  int outer_method(int);
  struct Inner {
    int inner_method(int);
  };
};
```

and trying to generate Java like

```
$ swig -java -c++ -module Sample nested.i
```

As a result 3 import and modifiers are appeared except `Outer::Inner class`.

Environment: MS Windows 7

```
$ swig -version

SWIG Version 3.0.7

Compiled with i586-mingw32msvc-g++ [i586-pc-mingw32msvc]

Configured options: +pcre

Please see http://www.swig.org for reporting bugs and further information
```

Answer (score 1):

`javaimports` do add code to import section, and while you are wrapping nested class, it is located inside single file and share same includes. `javaimports` for nested class is ignored.

---

personally for class documentation i use `javaclassmodifiers` like so:

```
%typemap(javaclassmodifiers) Outer::Inner "
/**
* Outer::Inner class
*/
public class";
```

in case of inner class it generates:

```
  static 
  /**
  * Outer::Inner class
  */
  public class Inner
```

which is not that very nice, it compiles, but javadoc is not generated for that class.